# Getting error while encrypting password using Python

Tags: python, bz2

I am getting the following error while encrypting the password using `bz2` module using Python. Here I am saving that encrypted value inside DB.

Error:

```
ProgrammingError at /signsave/
You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/signsave/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

Here is my code:

```
def signsave(request):
    """This function helps to save signup data"""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('uname')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        con_pass = request.POST.get('conpass')
        new_pass = bz2.compress(password) 
        if password == con_pass:
            passw = User(
                uname=name,
                password=new_pass,
                raw_password=password,
            )
            passw.save()
            message = "Registered successfully"
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {'msg': message})
        else:
            message = "The password did not match "
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/signup.html', {'msg': message})
```

Here when I am trying to save the encrypted value those errors are coming.

Comment: bz2 is a compression algorithm not an encryption algorithm. The passwords are effectively still stored in plaintext.

Comment: I think the problem is mostly that you use bz2 to compress (not encrypt) password. Passwords are usually hashed, then salted instead. This is a "destructive" process, as in once the password is processed, you can check easily if another input matches the password, but it is close to impossible to recover the password. Compression is a definitive no, encryption could be ok, hashing + salting is the recommended way

Comment: Can you give any idea about easy encryption algorithm.

Comment: @AnthonyRossi "hashing, then salting" is no longer sufficient. This is not secure, **do not do this**.

Comment: Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. `PBKDF2` is the NIST approved method for password verifiers. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use `bz2` for anything but compression. Use built-in [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) module instead.

Replace `bz2.compress(password` with `hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).digest()`. You'll get a SHA256 hash of your password string, which you can check against other string's hashes, proving their validity.

Comment: This is **not secure**, do not do this. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. See the comment to the question for more information.